# Spark Dataframe to add double quotes to all numeric column

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to add double quotes to all numeric columns in the spark data frame using scala

I have gone through this doc but there is no configuration to add double quotes to numeric columns.

doc link: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/QuoteMode.html

Input: `val someDF = Seq(
     |   ("user1", "math","algebra-1","90"),
     |   ("user1", "physics","gravity","70")
     | ).toDF("user_id", "course_id","lesson_name","score")`

Actual Output:

```
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|user_id|course_id|lesson_name|score|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|  user1|     math|  algebra-1|   90|
|  user1|  physics|    gravity|   70|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
```

Expected Output:

```
     someDF.show()
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|user_id|course_id|lesson_name|score|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|  user1|     math|  algebra-1| "90"|
|  user1|  physics|    gravity| "70"|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
``
```

Comment: do you mean you want to convert numeric column to string? Can you provide some input and output?

Comment: I have updated the question please check.

Comment: Any workaround for this? to handle only numeric columns

Comment: But your score column is already a string.

someDF.printSchema
root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- course_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lesson_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score: string (nullable = true)

Do you wish to explicitly have quotes around values of score column ?

Comment: Yes... Explicitly I need to add quotes to the score column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a UDF to do this modification.

Create dataframe

```
scala>val someDF = Seq(("user1", "math","algebra-1","90"),("user1", "physics","gravity","70")).toDF("user_id", "course_id","lesson_name","score")
```

Next, create a user defined function:

```
scala>val quoteStr = udf((scoreStr: String) =>  "\""+scoreStr+"\"")
```

Last, update the column values:

```
scala>someDF.withColumn("score",quoteStr($"score")).show(false)

+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|user_id|course_id|lesson_name|score|
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
|user1  |math     |algebra-1  |"90" |
|user1  |physics  |gravity    |"70" |
+-------+---------+-----------+-----+
```